# AngularJS - How to handle "chunked" data using $http?

Tags: angularjs

Currently have the following snippet implemented, which is just a basic GET call:

```
$http.get(url,
  {
    params: ...,
    responseType: 'json'
  }
).then(
  function success(response) {
    ...
  },
  function failure(reason) {
    ...
  }
);
```

I would like to extend it to support `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` so that I can progressively load results onto the screen as they come in. Is this currently possible using `$http` (angular@1.5.11)?